# How do I modify the page level permissions using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a site with page level permissions set. Each page inherits from the parent, but then stops at a certain point.  After a requirement is met, I want to allow access the the child pages.

The API has site level access, e.g.

```
site.addViewer(viewer)   
site.removeViewer(viewer)    
site.addCollaborator(collaborator)    
site.getCollaborators()    
site.removeCollaborator(collaborator)
```

But at the page level I only see

```
page.getAuthors
```

(Which I assume is the same as collaborators, but fail to see the reason for changing the name?)

Is it possible to change page level permission from a script in the site?

Comment: Usually Apps Scripts API lags behind Google API and other features. This is also one such example. Page level permissions are relatively new in Google Sites and Apps Scripts hasn't had the time to catch up yet.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be possible. [This issue in the Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1021) indicates that they're working on it. But this issue was created over a year ago, so I'm not sure the status of it...